# How to add pagination in active state even refresh the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Admin LTE theme I have a problem with it's datatable. I want to pagination tab active even on page refresh, can you please help me with this.

here is the URL of pagination table. https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/tables/data.html

image may clear to know my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Local Storage`

that's mean if user clicked button you set page number in `Local Storage` and if refresh page you get page number and active this page

Comment: Can you please give me the code to finish this problem.

Comment: see this page: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70969105/using-json-stringify-in-local-storage/70969218#70969218). you must in onClick button set a item to `local storage`